# Tomcat db2 jdbc connection problem

Tags: tomcat, jdbc, db2

Hi i want to connect db2 database on tomcat in a JSF 2.0 project.

While i was googling i saw a blogs which says that i should copy db2 jdbc jars into the catalina_home\lib directory.When i did so tomcat did not start.After i deleted jars.Tomcat now starts.But i wonder how can i connect db2 database on server.

Comment: You should look at errors when you had jar in catalina_home/lib and when Tomcat failed to start, and fix them. Maybe you had the same jar in your webapp's WEB-INF/lib, too?

Comment: it gives java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError.I added jars tomcat/lib folder.i couldn't connect db.later i added into the web-inf lib directory.Normally in a desktop application i added jar folders as external lib, it has connected.I wonder if should i find another jar.

Answer (score 1):

Webapp-specific JAR files should go in Webapp/WEB-INF/lib, not in Webapp/WEB-INF/classes. The Tomcat/lib should only be used for appserver specific libraries and optionally also JAR files which should be shared among the deployed webapplications.

There might be more into the IncompatibleClassChangeError, this can have an entirely different cause. But first try getting the JAR's in the right place. If in vain, then please update your question to include the detail message. This at least smells that you're putting JAR files of a different appserver make/version in the classpath.